# Is it possible to interpolate Array values in token?

Tags: raku

I'm working on [homoglyphs module](https://github.com/bbkr/HomoGlypher) and I have to build regular expression that can find homoglyphed text corresponding to ASCII equivalent.

So for example I have character with no homoglyph alternatives:

```
my $f = 'f';
```

and character that can be obfuscated:

```
my @o = 'o', 'о', 'ο'; # ASCII o, Cyrillic o, Greek omicron
```

I can easily build regular expression that will detect homoglyphed phrase 'foo':

```
say 'Suspicious!' if $text ~~ / $f @o @o /;
```

But how should I compose such regular expression if I don't know the value to detect in compile time? Let's say I want to detect phishing that contains homoglyphed 'cash' word in messages. I can build sequence with all the alternatives:

```
my @lookup = ['c', 'с', 'ϲ', 'ς'], ['a', 'а', 'α'], 's', 'h'; # arbitrary runtime length
```

Now obviously following solution cannot "unpack" array elements into the regular expression:

```
/ @lookup / # doing LTM, not searching elements in sequence
```

I can workaround this by manually quoting each element and compose text representation of alternatives to get string that can be evaluated as regular expression. And build token from that using string interpolation:

```
my $regexp-ish = textualize( @lookup ); # string "[ 'c' | 'с' | 'ϲ' | 'ς' ] [ 'a' | 'а' | 'α' ] 's' 'h'"
my $token = token { <$regexp-ish> }
```

But that is quite error-prone.
Is there any cleaner solution to **compose regular expression on the fly from arbitrary amount of elements not known at compile time**?

Comment: By the way - I know that I can build it also recursively, nesting each lookup part in subtoken: `my $token1 = token { @lookup[0] }; $token2 = token { <$token1> @lookup[1] };...` (that's syntax error of course, just showing the idea). However that does not produce "healthy" grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best approach to use.

I haven't implemented a confusables<sup>1</sup> module yet in `Intl::`, though I do plan on getting around to it eventually, here's two different ways I could imagine a token looking.<sup>2</sup>

```
my token confusable($source) {
  :my $i = 0;                                    # create a counter var
  [
    <?{                                          # succeed only if
      my $a = self.orig.substr: self.pos+$i, 1;  #   the test character A
      my $b = $source.substr: $i++, 1;           #   the source character B and

      so $a eq $b                                #   are the same or
      || $a eq %*confusables{$b}.any;            #   the A is one of B's confusables
    }> 
    .                                            # because we succeeded, consume a char
  ] ** {$source.chars}                           # repeat for each grapheme in the source
}
```

Here I used the dynamic hash `%*confusables` which would be populated in some way — that will depend on your module and may not even necessarily be dynamic (for example, having the signature `:($source, %confusables)` or referencing a module variable, etc.

You can then have your code work as follows:

```
say $foo ~~ /<confusable: 'foo'>/
```

This is probably the best way to go about things as it will give you a lot more control — I took a peak at your module and it's clear you want to enable 2-to-1 glyph relationships and eventually you'll probably want to be running code directly over the characters.

If you are okay with just 1-to-1 relationships, you can go with a much simpler token:

```
my token confusable($source) {
  :my @chars = $source.comb;            # split the source 
  @(                                    # match the array based on 
     |(                                 #   a slip of
        %confusables{@chars.head}       #     the confusables 
        // Empty                        #     (or nothing, if none)
     ),                                 #
     @a.shift                           #   and the char itself
   )                                    #
   ** {$source.chars}                   # repeating for each source char
}
```

The `@(…)` structure lets you effectively create an adhoc array to be interpolated.  In this case, we just slip in the confusables with the original, and that's that.  You have to be careful though because a non-existent hash item will return the type object `(Any)` and that messes things up here (hence `// Empty`)

In either case, you'll want to use arguments with your token, as constructing regexes on the fly is fraught with potential gotchas and interpolations errors.

---

<sup>1</sup>Unicode calls homographs both "visually similar characters" and "confusables".

<sup>2</sup>The dynamic hash here `%confusables` could be populated any number of ways, and may not necessarily need to be dynamic, as it could be populated via the arguments (using a signature like `:($source, %confusables)` or referencing a module variable.

Comment: That manual checking in eval block in token and then artificially consuming amount of characters equal to that match (so that token behaves like token for outside world) will do the trick. Final code will be waaay more complicated than you wrote, because there will be more than one path in many-to-many matching. For example if you have homoglyphs for `io` and `o` then checking `kiosk` will have `k [ io homoglyphs ] s k` and `k i [ o homoglyphs ] s k` to check against. But that's doable in regexp eval block. Thanks for detailed answer, it is really helpful!

Comment: `%confusables{@chars.head} with %confusables{@chars.head}` could be written `%confusables{@chars.head} // ()`. (The `()` can be `Empty`.)

Comment: raiph: duh, that's what I get for writing an answer late at night.  Thanks!

Comment: @PawelPabianbbkr There's quite a bit of interesting things that you can do with a `[ . { code } ]+`.  If you're looking to package it up into a module, you might want to take a look at my advent day post on fuzzy matching: https://rakuadventcalendar.wordpress.com/2019/12/15/day-15-santa-had-too-much-eggnog/  on ways to add some additional properties to the match object (for example, you might want to have ensure `Match` objects hold three values: the string matched against, the actual string, and for convenience, a boolean indicating if it was an identical match or a match-via-confusable)

Comment: @user0721090601 Regex::FuzzyToken was my primary inspiration to add tokens to my module. And seeing sub wrapped around token method to apply role to extend match object... wow :)

Comment: @PawelPabianbbkr I'm really glad it inspired you!  I have a lot of other special tokens planned (one, `<local-number>` is already available in beta, and I'm playing around with `<email>` for a standards-perfect email detector).  Next released one though will probably be `<local-alpha>` that can grab just `a..zA..Z` for English, but for Spanish would grab `a..záéíóúüñýA..ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑÝ`, rather than the current <alpha> that's probably more permissive than most would want.

Comment: @user0721090601 I think I've caught an error in your answer: `my $t = token { 'a' <?{ say self.pos }> 'r' }; 'bbbbbbbar' ~~ $t;` will say `0`. I'm pretty sure code should refer to position of the outer match object: `say $/.pos` gives `8`. Position inside token itself is not enough to correctly substring stuff.

Comment: @PawelPabianbbkr There seems to be a difference in calling and I'm not sure the root cause of it.  If you use `my token t { … }; 'bbbbbbbar' ~~ /<t>/` it works okay.  I'm not sure if this is a bug (generally, you don't match to tokens directly, so maybe and no one's caught it) or working as intended.

Comment: @user0721090601 Indeed. i've found one more difference: `my $t = token ( $x ) { $x }; 'bar' ~~ / b <$t: 'a'> r/ ` gives syntax error. If token is given as variable I cannot pass params to in. Or maybe there is magic syntax that I don't know about.

Answer (score 5):

The [`Unicode::Security`](https://github.com/JJ/perl6-unicode-security) module implements confusables by using the [Unicode consortium tables](https://github.com/JJ/perl6-unicode-security/tree/master/resources/data). It's actually not using regular expressions, just looking up different characters in those tables.

Comment: Thanks, I'll link it in my module doc. It's different approach (mine is focused on unwinding because it originated from International Domain Name phishing check tool) but for fast checking string against string yours is more elegant solution. And I'll definitely use some mapping inspirations from it.

Comment: Oh, hey, you already have it.  And given where Unicode keeps the data (I thought it was in CLDR but it's not), `Unicode::` is the perfect namespace for it.  Yay, one less thing for me to code :-)